CSS Set border-radius of select2 in input group
I want to set the border radius of this select2 in this input group to 0

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
  </span>
  <input type="hidden" id="default_customer_id" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" id="default_customer_name" value="KHÁCH LẺ">
  <input type="hidden" id="default_customer_balance" value="0.0000">
  <input type="hidden" id="default_customer_address" value="">
  <select class="form-control mousetrap select2-hidden-accessible" id="customer_id" required="" name="contact_id" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-required="true">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Enter Customer name / phone</option>
    <option value="1">KHÁCH LẺ</option>
  </select>
  <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 281.578px;">
    <span class="selection">
      <span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-customer_id-container">
        <span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-customer_id-container" title="KHÁCH LẺ">KHÁCH LẺ</span>
        <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
          <b role="presentation"></b>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
    <span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default bg-white btn-flat add_new_customer" data-name="">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-circle text-primary fa-lg"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>

I try this following code but it doesn't work:
.input-group .select2-container>.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){border-radius:0}

Can u guys help me ? Thanks !

please create a [mre]. your selector .select2-container>.select2-container--default should be .select2-container.select2-container--default

Your CSS select statement has two major issues.
First
.select2-container--default is a sibling for .select2-container but you are targeting it like it is a child of it (i.e .select2-container>.select2-container--default)
Second
While there is only one element with the class .select2-selection--single, and you target it with .select2-selection--single:not(:first-child):not(:last-child), the selector will not match the element. This is because the single .select2-selection--single element is both the first and the last child simultaneously.
In other words, The :not(:first-child) pseudo-class will exclude it since it's the first child, and the :not(:last-child) pseudo-class will exclude it as it's also the last child. Therefore, the element does not meet the conditions for this selector, so it will not be targeted.
Thus, the select statement should be:
.input-group .select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  border-radius: 0;
}

If you really need to select only those with .select2-container--default, then it should be like this:
.input-group .select2-container.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
  border-radius: 0;
}


I using this but now working: .input-group .select2-container.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){border-radius:0}
